# 'Cannot run program "docker"' when using withDockerRegistry in Declarative Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm in the middle of refactoring our old scripted jenkins pipeline and am trying to take advantage of the nice jenkins declarative syntax.
However I'm having issue trying to authenticate with our private docker registry.

The resources online tell me this should work:

```
            steps {
                sh 'docker -v'
                withDockerRegistry([url: DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL, credentialsId: DOCKER_REGISTRY_CREDENTIALS]) {
                    pushDockerImage()
                }
            }
```

The first line, "docker -v",  executes correctly and the current docker version is printed out.
However when it tries to execute "withDockerRegistry" it fails with:

> Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory

Do I have the syntax wrong or am I missing some sort of global config?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Add a toolName to the withDockerRegistry:

```
withDockerRegistry(registry: [url: DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL, credentialsId: DOCKER_REGISTRY_CREDENTIALS], toolName: 'docker')
```

Also setup docker in Global Tool Configuration.